# Stuck on pxe-mof exiting pxe rom while installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I just tried to install ubuntu on my own with a help of a youtube video and I got stuck on  a black screen with"pxe-mof:exiting pxe rom..." With this repeating.I don't know what to do please help me what to do

Comment: looks like your computer try to boot over network. Please check your  bootorder in uefi/bios.

Comment: Yeah! got it got stuck on the bootorder